# How can I put a pyblock in a box?

Tags: tables, python, pythontex, box

I'm learning using PythonTeX and I have a problem. I would like to put a pyblock inside a box on my document, I tried this two things, but TeXMaker never ends compiling

Option 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{settings/packages}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{pyblock}
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
import pandas
import scipy
print(6)
a = numpy.array([9])
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,5,6])
\end{pyblock}
}

\end{document}
```

Option 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{settings/packages}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline 
\begin{pyblock}
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
import pandas
import scipy
print(6)
a = numpy.array([9])
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,5,6])
\end{pyblock} \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

where settings/packages is a file with all packages are imported (\usepackage{pythontex})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual of PythonTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/pythontex.pdf) recommends to use `mdframed` in Section 3.1 Installing PythonTeX:

> The `mdframed` package is recommended for enclosing typeset code in
>   boxes with fancy borders and/or background colors

It also works for not-so-fancy borders, see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{pyblock}
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy
import pandas
import scipy
print(6)
a = numpy.array([9])
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,5,6])
\end{pyblock}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say I don't have an answer for you but when I wanted to do this and couldn't get it to work I used the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en) package instead. I simply made a listing that have python color coding and used the frame option to make a box around my listing.